# How to automatically check if there is any possible exceptions in Python?

Tags: python, exception, execution

I'm refactoring a non-trivial python project, there could be many exceptions to be thrown. sometimes it's hard to catch all of them if you don't just try...except the whole program.

In order to achieve a fine-grained exception handling, I want to systematically get a list(preferably a graph) of all possible exceptions( and their types) that could be thrown in different location of execution flow.

Is such a thing even[sic] possible?

Comment: Here is quite a comprehensive list of Python exceptions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

Comment: @Mika72 maybe I didn't phrase it correctly, I needed those which could be thrown from my program(and the exception sites), not every Python exceptions